# Objective-c Priority Queue

Tags: objective-c, collections, priority-queue

I've started using Objective-c for iOS programming. I switched over from Java, and I wanted to know if there were any existing libraries like the Java Collections Framework for Obj-c, more specifically a priority queue implementation. I've done some searches, but have been unable to come up with anything.

UPDATE: I found this, but would have no idea how to use it myself: http://www.ohloh.net/p/pqlib

Comment: I think closest to what you are looking for would be Grand Central Distpatch: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091

Comment: It looks like an NSMutableArray searched with `indexOfObjectPassingTest` would work pretty well.

Comment: NSOperationQueue looks like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to find an implementation of a priority queue, so I went ahead and made my own. I'm not sure how robust it is, but I hope it might point others in the right direction.

PriorityQueue.h

```
//
//  PriorityQueue.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "comparable.h"

//Implements a priority queue. All objects in queue must implement the comparable protocol and must be all of the same type. The queue can be explicity typed at initialization, otherwise the type of the first object entered will be the type of the queue
@interface PriorityQueue : NSObject{
    NSMutableArray *queue;
    Class type;
}

- (id)init;
- (id)initWithObjects:(NSSet *)objects;
- (id)initWithCapacity:(int)capacity;
- (id)initWithCapacity:(int)capacity andType:(Class)oType; //Queue will reject objects not of that type

#pragma mark - Useful information
- (BOOL)isEmpty;
- (BOOL)contains:(id<comparable, NSObject>)object;
- (Class)typeOfAllowedObjects; //Returns the type of objects allowed to be stored in the queue
- (int) size;

#pragma mark - Mutation
- (void)clear;
- (BOOL)add:(id<comparable, NSObject>)object;
- (void)remove:(id<comparable, NSObject>)object;

#pragma mark - Getting things out
- (id)peek;
- (id)poll;
- (id)objectMatchingObject:(id<comparable, NSObject>)object;
- (NSArray *)toArray;

#pragma mark -
- (void)print;

@end
```

PriorityQueue.m

```
//
//  PriorityQueue.m
//

#import "PriorityQueue.h"

#define INITIAL_CAPACITY 50
@implementation PriorityQueue

#pragma mark - Initialization
- (id)init{
    return [self initWithCapacity:INITIAL_CAPACITY andType:nil];
}

- (id)initWithObjects:(NSSet *)objects{
    self = [self initWithCapacity:INITIAL_CAPACITY andType:nil];
    for (id<comparable, NSObject>object in objects){
        [self add:object];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCapacity:(int)capacity{
    return [self initWithCapacity:capacity andType:nil];
}

- (id)initWithCapacity:(int)capacity andType:(Class)oType{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        queue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        type = oType;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Useful information
- (BOOL)isEmpty{
    if(queue.count == 0){
        return YES;
    }
    else{ return NO;}
}

- (BOOL)contains:(id<comparable, NSObject>)object{
    //Search the array to see if the object is already there
    for(id<comparable> o in queue){
        if([o isEqual:object]){
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}

- (Class)typeOfAllowedObjects{
    NSLog(@"Allowed Types: %@", type);
    return type;
}

- (int) size{
    return [queue count];
}

#pragma mark - Mutation
//Mutation
- (void)clear{
    [queue removeAllObjects];
}

//A "greater" object (compareTo returns 1) is at the end of the queue.
- (BOOL)add:(id<comparable, NSObject>)object{
    //Make sure the object's type is the same as the type of the queue
    if(type == nil){
//        NSLog(@"Type is nil");
        type = [object class];
    }
    if([object class] != type){
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Trying to add incorrect object");
        return NO;
    }

    if([queue count] == 0){
        [queue addObject:object];
        return YES;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < [queue count]; i++){
        if([object compareTo:queue[i]] < 0){
            [queue insertObject:object atIndex:i];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    [queue addObject:object];
    return YES;
}

- (void)remove:(id<comparable, NSObject>)object{
    [queue removeObject:object];
}

#pragma mark - Getting things out
- (id)peek{
    return queue[0];
}

- (id)poll{
    //Get the object at the front
    id head = queue[0];

    //Remove and return that object
    [queue removeObject:head];
    return head;
}

- (id)objectMatchingObject:(id<comparable, NSObject>)object{
    //Search the array to see if the object is already there
    for(id<comparable> o in queue){
        if([o isEqual:object]){
            return o;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSArray *)toArray{
    return [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:queue];
}

#pragma mark -
- (NSString *)description{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PriorityQueue: %@ allows objects of type %@", queue, type];
}

- (void)print{
    NSLog(@"%@", [self description]);
}

@end
```

Comparable.h

```
//
//  comparable.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


//NOTE: Class must check to make sure it is the same class as whatever is passed in
@protocol comparable

- (int)compareTo:(id<comparable, NSObject>)object;
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id<comparable, NSObject>)object;

@end
```

Comment: This implements the interface of a priority queue, but a typical priority queue will have O(log N) insert and remove operations, not O(N) like this. That can make a big difference for decent sized N.

Answer (score 2):

See https://mikeash.com/pyblog/using-evil-for-good.html where Mike implements Objective-C wrapper for C++ STD priority queue.

Answer (score 1):

CFBinaryHeap can be used as a Priority Queue and is described as such in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBinaryHeapRef/

The downsides seem to be:

1) There is no remove or update element capability.  As far as I can tell you can only remove the min element.

2) It is very C-like and not very pleasant to use in Objc or Swift.

Comment: The thing that worries me is that the documentation makes no guarantee that the minimum object that you "peek" may not be the same one that you "pop". So peeking and then removing that element only if necessary doesnt' seem safe.

Answer (score 1):

My approach supporting value updates. As CFBinaryHeap does not support updating values I put them on an invalidation list and once being extracted the object is inserted again and a new extraction is made.

```
/**
 Objective-C wrapper around CFBinaryHeap implementing a priority queue and extended by updating a previous value
 */

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface BEPriorityQueue<ObjectType, ValueType> : NSObject

- (void)dispose;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger count;

- (void)insert:(ObjectType)object value:(ValueType)value;
- (void)update:(ObjectType)object value:(ValueType)value;

/** returns and removes object with lowest value (highest priority */
- (ObjectType)extractMinimum;

- (BOOL)containsObject:(ObjectType)object;
- (id)valueForObject:(id)object;

- (void)removeAllObjects;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

With this implementation:

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface BEPriorityQueue()

- (CFComparisonResult)compareObject:(id)object1 with:(id)object2;

@end

static CFComparisonResult BEPriorityQueueCompareItems(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2, void *info)
{
    id object1 = (__bridge id)ptr1;
    id object2 = (__bridge id)ptr2;

    BEPriorityQueue* queue = (__bridge id)info;
    return [queue compareObject:object1 with:object2];
}

static const void *BEPriorityQueueItemRetain(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *ptr) {
    return CFRetain(ptr);
}

static void BEPriorityQueueItemRelease(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *ptr) {
    CFRelease(ptr);
}

@implementation BEPriorityQueue
{
    BOOL                _disposed;
    CFBinaryHeapRef     _binaryHeapRef;
    NSMapTable*         _objectToValue;
    NSMutableSet*       _invalidated;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {

        CFBinaryHeapCallBacks callbacks = (CFBinaryHeapCallBacks) {
            .version = 0,
            .retain = &BEPriorityQueueItemRetain,
            .release = &BEPriorityQueueItemRelease,
            .copyDescription = &CFCopyDescription,
            .compare = &BEPriorityQueueCompareItems
        };

        CFBinaryHeapCompareContext compareContext = (CFBinaryHeapCompareContext) {
            .version = 0,
            .info = (__bridge void *)(self),
            .retain = NULL,
            .release = NULL,
            .copyDescription = NULL,
        };

        _binaryHeapRef = CFBinaryHeapCreate(NULL, 0, &callbacks, &compareContext);
        _objectToValue = [NSMapTable strongToStrongObjectsMapTable];
        _invalidated = [NSMutableSet set];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self dispose];

    if (_binaryHeapRef != NULL)
    {
        CFRelease(_binaryHeapRef);
        _binaryHeapRef = NULL;
    }
}

- (void)dispose
{
    [self removeAllObjects];
    _disposed = YES;
}

#pragma mark internal

- (CFComparisonResult)compareObject:(id)object1 with:(id)object2
{
    id value1 = [_objectToValue objectForKey:object1];
    id value2 = [_objectToValue objectForKey:object2];
    return (CFComparisonResult)[value1 compare:value2];
}

#pragma mark interface

- (NSUInteger)count
{
    BEEnsureFalse(_disposed);
    return (NSUInteger)CFBinaryHeapGetCount(_binaryHeapRef);
}

- (id)extractMinimum
{
    BEEnsureFalse(_disposed);

    const void *ptr = NULL;
    if (!CFBinaryHeapGetMinimumIfPresent(_binaryHeapRef, &ptr))
        return nil;

    id object = (__bridge id)ptr;
    id value = [_objectToValue objectForKey:object];

    CFBinaryHeapRemoveMinimumValue(_binaryHeapRef);
    [_objectToValue removeObjectForKey:object];

    // if the objects was invalidated, it may no longer be the minimum
    // therefore reinsert the object and extract again
    if ([_invalidated containsObject:object])
    {
        [_invalidated removeObject:object];
        [self insert:object value:value];
        return [self extractMinimum];
    }

    return object;
}

- (void)insert:(id)object value:(id)value
{
    BEEnsureFalse(_disposed);
    BEEnsureIsNotNil(object);
    BEEnsureIsNotNil(value);
    BEEnsureTrue([value respondsToSelector:@selector(compare:)]); // <NSComparable>

    [_objectToValue setObject:value forKey:object]; // first to be available furing insertion compare
    CFBinaryHeapAddValue(_binaryHeapRef, (__bridge void *)object);
}

- (void)update:(id)object value:(id)value
{
    BEEnsureFalse(_disposed);
    BEEnsureIsNotNil(object);
    BEEnsureTrue([value respondsToSelector:@selector(compare:)]); // <NSComparable>

    [_objectToValue setObject:value forKey:object]; // first to be available during insertion compare
    [_invalidated addObject:object];
}

- (BOOL)containsObject:(id)object
{
    BEEnsureFalse(_disposed);
    return CFBinaryHeapContainsValue(_binaryHeapRef, (__bridge void *)object);
}

- (id)valueForObject:(id)object
{
    return [_objectToValue objectForKey:object];
}

- (void)removeAllObjects
{
    CFBinaryHeapRemoveAllValues(_binaryHeapRef);
    [_objectToValue removeAllObjects];
    [_invalidated removeAllObjects];
}

@end


NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```